# ExpressJs static files not working correctly

Tags: javascript, express

I have an express app and the static files are not working for every route.
When I get to '/', the static styles and images work perfectly when index.ejs is rendered.
When I get '/efbhew', a route that doesn't exist, 404.ejs renders ok.
When I get '/asdw/feff' or other routes like '/df/fg/dfgdfg/sfgd', the static styles and images do not work. Is there something else I have to do in order for it to work?

Below is my code.

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.find({}).limit(7).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).exec();

    res.render('index.ejs', {
        latestPosts: posts
    });
});


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404.ejs');
});
```

This is the structure of my folders:

[image]

I tried changing the path of the public folders to go deeper since when I got to '/asdf/wfds/sdfsd', the image source is 'http://localhost:3000/asdf/wfds/img/logo.png' and it cant find it. But that still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `ejs` page at `/df/fg/dfgdfg/sfgd` references a static file, as in

```html
<img src="img/logo.png"/>
```

the URL is relative to the URL of the `ejs` page, so in this example it would be `/df/fg/dfgdfg/img/logo.png` (note the last segment `sfgd` is dropped, that's why it works for a page at `/efbhew`).

But the image exists only as `/img/logo.png`. Therefore, you should always address it with a path that starts with a slash, as in

```html
<img src="/img/logo.png"/>
```